# How to store last selected button

Tags: ios

I have created one quizz application.

There is label for displaying question and four buttons for displaying answer.

On clicking next button questions and all Options changed and fetched from the array.

But while clicking previous button all checkboxes were cleared. how to store previous selection of button.

This is my code

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        k = 0;
        ansCount = 0;
        NSLog(@"%d",ansCount);
        self.btnFinish.hidden = YES;
        self.btnPrevious.hidden = YES;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        arrAddQues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        arrAddOption1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        arrAddOption2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        arrAddOption3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        arrAddOption4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        arrAns = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        Facilities *facility = [[Facilities alloc]init];

        NSMutableArray *arrayData = [facility selectData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from ios"]];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayData.count ; i++) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[arrayData objectAtIndex:i]);
                }
        for(NSDictionary *dict in arrayData)
        {
            NSString *str = [dict valueForKey:@"question"];
            NSString *str1 = [dict valueForKey:@"option1"];
            NSString *str2 = [dict valueForKey:@"option2"];
            NSString *str3 = [dict valueForKey:@"option3"];
            NSString *str4 = [dict valueForKey:@"option4"];
            NSString *str5 = [dict valueForKey:@"ans"];
            NSLog(@"%@",str);
            [arrAddQues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str]];
            [arrAddOption1 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str1]];
            [arrAddOption2 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str2]];
            [arrAddOption3 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str3]];
            [arrAddOption4 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str4]];
            [arrAns addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str5]];
        }

        NSLog(@"Final Array..............%@",arrAddQues);
        NSLog(@"Ans:---%@",arrAns);
        self.lblQues1.text = [arrAddQues objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.btnOption1 setTitle:[arrAddOption1 objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnOption2 setTitle:[arrAddOption2 objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnOption3 setTitle:[arrAddOption3 objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnOption4 setTitle:[arrAddOption4 objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
- (IBAction)click_Previous:(id)sender {
    if (k == 1) {
        self.btnPrevious.hidden = YES;
        k--;
        self.lblQues1.text = [arrAddQues objectAtIndex:k];
        [self.btnOption1 setTitle:[arrAddOption1 objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnOption2 setTitle:[arrAddOption2 objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnOption3 setTitle:[arrAddOption3 objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnOption4 setTitle:[arrAddOption4 objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }

    else if (k < arrAddQues.count) {
        NSLog(@"value %d",k);
        self.btnNext.hidden = NO;
        self.btnPrevious.hidden = NO;
        self.btnFinish.hidden = YES;
        k--;
        self.lblQues1.text = [arrAddQues objectAtIndex:k];
        [self.btnOption1 setTitle:[arrAddOption1 objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnOption2 setTitle:[arrAddOption2 objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnOption3 setTitle:[arrAddOption3 objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnOption4 setTitle:[arrAddOption4 objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
ansCount--;
        NSLog(@"%d",ansCount);

        if (k == arrAddQues.count -1) {
            k--;
            self.btnNext.hidden = YES;
            self.btnFinish.hidden = NO;
            self.btnPrevious.hidden = NO;
        }

    }
}

- (IBAction)click_Next:(id)sender {
    if (k < arrAddQues.count -1) {
        self.btnNext.hidden = NO;
        self.btnFinish.hidden = YES;
        self.btnPrevious.hidden = NO;
        if (temp == 1) {
            temp = 0;
            if ([self.btnOption1.currentTitle isEqualToString:[arrAns objectAtIndex:k]]) {
                ansCount++;
                NSLog(@"%d",ansCount);

            }
        }
        else if(temp == 2)
        {
            temp = 0;
            if ([self.btnOption2.currentTitle isEqualToString:[arrAns objectAtIndex:k]]) {
                ansCount++;
                NSLog(@"%d",ansCount);

            }

        }
        else if (temp == 3)
        {
            temp = 0;
            if ([self.btnOption3.currentTitle isEqualToString:[arrAns objectAtIndex:k]]) {
                ansCount++;
                NSLog(@"%d",ansCount);

            }
        }
        else if (temp == 4)
        {
            temp = 0;
            if ([self.btnOption4.currentTitle isEqualToString:[arrAns objectAtIndex:k]]) {
                ansCount++;
                NSLog(@"%d",ansCount);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Wrong Answer!!!!!!!");
        }
        k++;
        self.lblQues1.text = [arrAddQues objectAtIndex:k];
        [self.btnOption1 setTitle:[arrAddOption1 objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnOption2 setTitle:[arrAddOption2 objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnOption3 setTitle:[arrAddOption3 objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnOption4 setTitle:[arrAddOption4 objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        self.imageOp1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
        self.imageOp2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
        self.imageOp3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
        self.imageOp4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
        if (k == arrAddQues.count -1) {
            self.btnNext.hidden = YES;
            self.btnFinish.hidden = NO;
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)click_Option1:(UIButton *)sender {
    temp = sender.tag;
    self.imageOp1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox-tic.png"];
    self.imageOp2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
    self.imageOp3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
    self.imageOp4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
}

- (IBAction)click_Option2:(UIButton *)sender {
    temp = sender.tag;
    self.imageOp1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
    self.imageOp2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox-tic.png"];
    self.imageOp3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
    self.imageOp4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
}

- (IBAction)click_Option3:(UIButton *)sender {
    temp = sender.tag;
    self.imageOp1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
    self.imageOp2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
    self.imageOp3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox-tic.png"];
    self.imageOp4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
}

- (IBAction)click_Option4:(UIButton *)sender {
    temp = sender.tag;
    self.imageOp1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
    self.imageOp2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
    self.imageOp3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
    self.imageOp4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox-tic.png"];
}
```

Comment: This may be a bit hacky but you can use a static array of size one to store the last selection. YOu can save the actual button or the state information of the button. If you want to save state, a static dictionary may do. Static is good because it remembers data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You need to save selected item on - (IBAction)click_Option:(UIButton *)sender to ur array

add one more field to ur array like **selectedAns:"1"**

- (IBAction)click_Previous:(id)sender {

sender=[arr objectatindex:k];
switch(selectedAns)
{

case 1:
self.imageOp1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox-tic.png"];
    self.imageOp2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
    self.imageOp3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
    self.imageOp4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
case 2:

self.imageOp2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox-tic.png"];
    self.imageOp1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
    self.imageOp3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
    self.imageOp4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkcox.png"];
case 3:
case 4:

}
}

Save data to this format Array{ dictionary {
question:@"",ans1:"",ans2:@""...}, dictionary{question:@"",ans1:"",ans2:@""...},.....}
for easy access, Hope this will help u
```